# What is the difference between "(not set)" and "(not provided)" in the Google Analytics keywords?

Tags: google-analytics, keywords

In Google Analytics, I noticed that I have quite a few people coming in with a search keyword of **(not set)**. I'm assuming this is simply when they came directly to my site without the help of a search engine.

But I've also noticed the keyword **(not provided)**. What does that mean? Where's the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### (not set)

This is the value that is placed in the keyword column when the user did not use a search engine to find your site.

### (not provided)

This is the value that is placed in the keyword column when the users search query was encrypted.

Encrypted search is the [default for users that are logged into their Google account](http://analytics.blogspot.de/2011/10/making-search-more-secure-accessing.html).

> #### How will this change impact Google Analytics users?
>
> When a signed in user visits your site from an organic Google search, all web analytics services, including Google Analytics, will continue to recognize the visit as Google “organic” search, but **will no longer report the query terms that the user searched on to reach your site.**

*(emphasis mine)*

Comment: rather than "encrypted", I would say that the keyword was "removed" from the referrer.  I've never seen one scrambled before, only completely stripped out.