# Google Analytics: (not set) showing up in SEO > Queries

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics

I have linked my GA account to my Webmaster Tools account, so I'm getting access to the Search Engine Optmization -> Queries report.  But the top query listed in that report is (not set).

Note: this is NOT (not provided) -- it's (not set).  Also, I have linked my Adwords account to GA as well.  And I'm using Universal Analytics

This (not set) item currently represents 42% of impressions and 52% of clicks.

I saw this post here, which says that (not set) means these people came to my site directly:

[What is the difference between "(not set)" and "(not provided)" in the Google Analytics keywords?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/51091/what-is-the-difference-between-not-set-and-not-provided-in-the-google-an)

However, if that's the case, then howcome (not set) shows values for clicks, average position, and CTR?

I am seeing thousands of other queries in my list, but having 52% of clicks invisible to me is kind of annoying.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?  Or is this just data that's not accessible to me, for some unknown reason?

Answer (score 1):

Due to Secure Search, Google do not provide search terms( for logged users). For this reason, nearly half of visits are either not provided or not set.

Comment: That is the explanation for Google Analytics organic keyword traffic. We've need verification from Google that it is the same for Search Console query data.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of sites (including mine) report the same thing, it could be an issue with Google.  I've read that it's being looked at internally by them.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics provides minimal query insights. Create a property in Google Search Console for more detailed search term performance data.

[image: Add property in GSC]

Adding properties will allow you to collect page and query data driven from organic Google searches, as well as monitoring technical performance and changes. Properties are easy to create; one only needs to verify root domain in GSC and then new properties can be created.

Comment: Such a short answer is not high quality.